# generator.visit of pycparser displaying wrong output in Ubuntu 16.04.3

Tags: python, ubuntu, pycparser

I have written the following program using pycparser and pycparserext:

```
from pycparser import parse_file,c_parser, c_ast, c_generator
from pycparserext.ext_c_parser import GnuCParser


content="int main() { int x = 1; int y = 0; while (y < 1000 && __VERIFIER_nondet_int()) { x = x + y; y = y + 1; } __VERIFIER_assert(x >= y); return 0;}"

text = r""" """+content
parser = GnuCParser()
ast = parser.parse(text)
generator = c_generator.CGenerator()
print str(generator.visit(ast))
```

When I run the code in Mac it returns the correct output. But when I run the same code in Ubuntu 16.04.3 it returns the following incorrect output (that is missing the 'main()':

```
int{
  int x = 1;
  int y = 0;
  while ((y < 1000) && __VERIFIER_nondet_int())
  {
    x = x + y;
    y = y + 1;
  }

  __VERIFIER_assert(x >= y);
  return 0;
}
```

What is causing this incorrect output?

Comment: Just to be clear: is the issue that it dropped the main() in the output?

Comment: yes . main() and any other function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably an issue with `pycparserext`. Using vanilla pycparser cloned fresh from Github, I get (running from the main pycparser directory):

```
$ cat /tmp/2.c
int main() { int x = 1; int y = 0; while (y < 1000 && __VERIFIER_nondet_int()) { x = x + y; y = y + 1; } __VERIFIER_assert(x >= y); return 0;}

$ PYTHONPATH=. python examples/c-to-c.py /tmp/2.c
int main()
{
  int x = 1;
  int y = 0;
  while ((y < 1000) && __VERIFIER_nondet_int())
  {
    x = x + y;
    y = y + 1;
  }

  __VERIFIER_assert(x >= y);
  return 0;
}
```

So I suggest you open an [issue for pycparserext](https://github.com/inducer/pycparserext/issues)